# @Retryable with Spring @Transactional

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-retry

I have a project whrere I need to use retriable on a transactional method. Let's say I want to update some client informations and I need to retry updating 2 times untill .

I put in my pom dependecy for

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In my @Configuration class I have @EnableRetry.
In my @Service class I defined a method:

```
>  @Retryable(value = CannotAcquireLockException.class, maxAttempts = 3,
> backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000,multiplier = 2,maxDelay = 5000))
>     @Transactional
>     public void updateClient (String info) throws Exception {
>         updateClientFromDB(info);
>     }
```

I test my method from Junit5 and seems that @Retryable doesn't work . I lock a row in db and when I run the test it seems does not retry, it loop endless.

```
> @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) 
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = {DSConfig.class }) 
> @ActiveProfiles({ "test" }) 
> @Slf4j class Test {
> 
> @Test     
> void retryTest() {        
>  String info = "Test";        
>  updateClient(info);  } }
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that Retryable IS working since the code is "looping", and the real issue is that it is not stopping a 3 attempts as you expected. Right?

As others have asked, are you receiving any exceptions or console messages?

Answer (score 0):

does updateClientFromDB throw CannotAcquireLockException?